# R: Compare and filtering of two data.frames based on conditions

Tags: r, filter, compare, dataframe, matching

I have a `data.frame` `data_qual` that looks like this:

```
data_qual <- structure(list(NAME = structure(1:3, .Label = c("NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME3"), class = "factor"), ID = c(56L, 47L, 77L), YEAR = c(1990L, 2007L, 1899L), VALUE = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ST", "X"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "YEAR", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

 NAME   ID YEAR    VALUE
1 NAME1 56 1990     X
2 NAME2 47 2007    ST
3 NAME3 77 1899    ST
```

I'd like to filter out values from `data_qual` by comparing it to another dataframe `dat`:

```
dat <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NAME1","NAME2"), class = "factor"), ID = c(56L, 56L, 56L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L), YEAR = c(1988L, 1989L, 1991L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L), VALUE = c(45L, 28L, 28L, -12L, 14L, 23L, 32L)), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "YEAR", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

  NAME  ID YEAR   VALUE
1 NAME1 56 1988    45
2 NAME1 56 1989    28
3 NAME1 56 1991    28
4 NAME2 47 2005   -12
5 NAME2 47 2006    14
6 NAME2 47 2007    23
7 NAME2 47 2008    32
```

How could I filter `data_qual` based on the column `ID` so that in a first filtering process only rows are written to a new `data.frame` that have a matching `ID` with `dat`?

```
   NAME ID YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 56 1990     X
2 NAME2 47 2007    ST
```

Then after that I am looking for a way that from the resulting data.frame only rows should be written out that don't have the same `YEAR` per group (as defined by `ID`)

```
   NAME ID YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 56 1990     X
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested in the intermediate step as well or directly the final step?

Comment: the intermediate step would be good to see so that I can control my data a little bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part

```
dat2 <- data_qual[data_qual$ID %in% dat$ID, ]
dat2
   NAME ID YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 56 1990     X
2 NAME2 47 2007    ST
```

And then for the second part

```
good_rows <- lapply(paste(dat2$ID, dat2$YEAR, sep = ":"), grepl, x = paste(dat$ID, dat$YEAR, sep = ":"))
dat3 <- dat2[!unlist(lapply(good_rows, any)), ]
```

Or if that's too messy for you, a for loop

```
good_rows <- vector(length = nrow(dat2))
for (i in 1:nrow(dat2)) {
   good_rows[i] <- !any(grepl(dat2$YEAR[i], dat[dat$ID == dat2$ID[i], "YEAR"]))
}
dat3 <- dat2[good_rows, ]
dat3
   NAME ID YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 56 1990     X
```